# objc_msgSend macro on arm64

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I'm trying to understand the difference between `id objc_msgSend(id self, SEL op, ...)` and `void objc_msgSend(void)`

I have this macro that worked for methods of all types. However, when transitioning to arm64, this version of objc_msgSend is no longer available.

```
#define safePerformSelector(target, selector, ...) ([target respondsToSelector:selector] ? objc_msgSend(target, selector, ##__VA_ARGS__) : nil)
```

This is what I've come up with so far but it seems to only work for methods that return an object and fails for those that don't.

```
#define safePerformSelector(target, selector, ...) ([target respondsToSelector:selector] ? ((id (*)(id, SEL, ...))objc_msgSend)(target, selector, ##__VA_ARGS__) : nil)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must always cast `objc_msgSend()` to the correct function pointer type first. Type `id(*)(id, SEL, ...)` is not the correct type, unless your method really does return `id` and accept `...` (which IIRC is syntactically impossible).

If you call `objc_msgSend()` with an incorrect function type then the called method may not receive parameter values correctly.

Comment: I didn't need to cast anything using my original macro. It worked great for all kinds of methods.

Comment: On some method signatures and some architectures, it will fail. In particular it will almost always do the wrong thing on arm64.

Comment: This problem did arise when transitioning to arm64. I suppose what you're saying is that I won't be able to accomplish this anymore? At least not as cleanly.

Comment: Is it possible to accomplish this using a single macro on all architectures?

Comment: It is not possible to use a single macro that is valid for all method signatures on all architectures.

Comment: Not even using a different approach? NSInvocation looks promising.

Comment: Trust that @GregParker knows what he's talking about!

Comment: Why not use an `#ifdef` per architecture?

Comment: You could use a different definition for each architecture and each method signature. You can't safely handle arbitary method signatures even on a single architecture.

Comment: Why is this so simple and straight forward on x86 but impossible to achieve on arm64? I don't understand why a change in architecture would cause this.

Comment: It's not simple on x86_64. Your macro is wrong for some method signatures there too. arm64 makes it worse because its ABI has more places where a vararg call and a non-vararg call differ.

Comment: @GregParker What method signatures is it incorrect for on x86_64?

Comment: Any method that has a parameter of type `float`, for starters.